# Navigating to new view on button press AFTER api response

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've got the following view:

```
struct FormView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = MyViewModel(myService: MyService())
    
    @State private var title: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(
                "Type something",
                text: $title
            )
                
            Button(action: onSubmit) {
                Text("Submit")
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: vm.post != nil) { oldValue, newValue in
            // Navigate here
        }
    }
    
    func onSubmit() {
        vm.submit(title: fieldTitle)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a Submit button that calls the api on press. I want to navigate to a new view AFTER the api response has returned, i.e. when `onChange(of: vm.post != nil) {}` is called.

But I'm not really sure how best to do this. I'm finding examples on how to do this on button press (with no api call), but not WITH an api call.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? How does it not work?

Comment: @Sweeper It works to the point where it calls the `onChange`, but at this point I'm not sure how to navigate to another page.

Comment: Do you have a `NavigationStack` or `NavigationSplitView`? If you do, then you can simply append new items to the navigation path, or use `navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)` and set the binding to true.

Comment: Append to a navigation stack trigger an isPresented or is active for older support. Use one if the “item” based presentations. You haven’t provided enough info.

Comment: I would like to support iOS 13+, and pass `vm.post` to the new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach where you use a `NavigationStack` and a `navigationDestination`
to navigate to a new view when you press your submit button and after fetching the new data from the api response:

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            FormView()
        }
    }
}

protocol MyServiceProtocol {
    func submit(title: String)
}

struct MyService: MyServiceProtocol {
    var name: String = "namename"
    func submit(title: String){ }
}

struct Post: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String = "PostPost"
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let myService: MyServiceProtocol
    @Published var post: Post?
    
    init(myService: MyServiceProtocol) {
        self.myService = myService
    }

    func submit(title: String) {
        // simulated fetching and changing the model post
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
            self.post = Post(name: "newpostname") // <-- for testing
        }
    }
}

struct FormView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = MyViewModel(myService: MyService())
    
    @State private var title: String = ""
    @State private var toNextView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Type something", text: $title).border(.red)
            
            Button(action: onSubmit) {
                Text("Submit")
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
        .onChange(of: vm.post) { oldValue, newValue in
            if vm.post != nil { // <-- adjust if need be
                toNextView = true
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $toNextView) {
            TheNextView().environmentObject(vm)
        }
    }
    
    func onSubmit() {
        vm.submit(title: title)
    }
}

struct TheNextView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: MyViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("TheNextView post: \(vm.post?.name ?? "no name")")
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

You can of course just pass the `post` to the next view,
such as:

```
 .navigationDestination(isPresented: $toNextView) {
     TheNextView(post: vm.post)
 }
 
 struct TheNextView: View {
     @State var post: Post?
     
     var body: some View {
         Text("TheNextView post: \(post?.name ?? "no name")")
     }
 }
```